# Payload size in Firebase reverse-proxy

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, middleware, firebase-hosting

Is there any payload size for apps hosted on Firebase or the only way to limit the payload is to use some kind of middleware?

Otherwise do we need to configure this on our own using Express? An example from Node.js best practices: https://github.com/i0natan/nodebestpractices/blob/security-best-practices-section/sections/security/requestpayloadsizelimit.md#example-code-for-express

Comment: Are you talking about using Firebase Hosting to serve content from an Express app deployed to Cloud Functions?

Comment: @DougStevenson exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas), Cloud Functions has a hard limit of 10 MB for HTTP request and response payloads.  There's nothing you can do to increase this limit.  I assume it's possible to impose your own smaller limit by checking the request or response, but once the response is received, you will have already paid the cost of the bandwidth and function invocation.